# How to display only 3 numbers on the X-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My current results look as follows:

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.title('Number of Passengers by Class', size=18)
plt.bar([1, 2, 3], [ttick, ftick, stick], width=.5)
ax.set_xlabel('Pclass', size=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Count', size=15)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I just need 1, 2, 3 displaying on my X-axis and formatted as integers.

Comment: X-axis is set to [1,2,3] as a string of ['1','2','3'].

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], rotation=90)
```